# Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL validation response code is 200 instead of 422

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Why validation response code and unathuntication status code is 200(ok) instead of 422 and 401 ?
how can i find request is failed to show error to users when all response codes are 200?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread for an explanation why it's 200 always: https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/279